# C# how to check if all array elements are visible

Tags: c#

My program creates 5 different labels with a cube form and they just drop down. When I press on them, they come invisible. I want to check if all of them are invisible, but don't know how to do so. Tried going through this site, found a solution with bool, but it just doesn't work my way. Also when my labels appear,you can see only 4 of them.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Label [] kubeliai = new Label [5];
    int poz = 100;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kubeliai.Length; i++)
        {
            kubeliai[i] = new Label();
            Controls.Add(kubeliai[i]);
            Random pos = new Random();
            kubeliai[i].Top = 50;
            kubeliai[i].Left = poz;
            poz += pos.Next(50, 200);
            kubeliai[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            kubeliai[i].Height = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Width = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Click += new EventHandler(kubelio_clickas);
        }

        Timer kritimo_laikrodis = new Timer();
        kritimo_laikrodis.Interval = 10;
        kritimo_laikrodis.Tick += new EventHandler(laikrodis);
        kritimo_laikrodis.Enabled = true;
    }
    void kubelio_clickas (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)sender).Visible = false;
    }
    void laikrodis (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kubeliai.Length; i++)
        {
            kubeliai[i].Top += 1;
            if (kubeliai.All.Visible == false) // this is an error
            {
                kubeliai[i].Visible = true;
                kubeliai[i].Top = 50;
                Random pos = new Random();
                poz += pos.Next(50, 200);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: loop thru the array and check the visible property.  BTW you should create the Random object once outside the loop.  In fact create one form/calll level once for the entire form

Comment: `kubeliai.All.Visible == false` is an error right?.. please indicate that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq you can check if all are invisible in this way

```
var areAllInvisible = kubeliai.All(l => l.Visible == false);
if (areAllInvisible)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when my labels appear you can see only 4 of them.

That's because the way you are picking random numbers is picking the same numbers each time and you are therefore placing your labels on top of each other. Read the first paragraph of the [`Random()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

Use `new Random()` once in your class definition like this:

```
Label [] kubeliai = new Label [5];
Random pos = new Random();
```

And remove it everywhere else in your program.